# localStorage Getting Undefined State

Tags: reactjs, redux

**TL;DR:** State updates correctly (viewed from Redux DevTools) but does not persist in Local Storage as it says that the state is "`undefined`" (screenshots attached).

**Explanation:**
I am new to Redux. I am trying to save my state to Local Storage. The state is updating correctly when I view from Redux DevTools and `console.log()` statements. However, when I check the application's local storage, it shows that the state is undefined.

**What I am trying to do:**
I am adding a service to my cart whenever I press the "Add" button in one of my components (which I then want to save to the Local Storage of the browser).

Here are the screenshots from Redux DevTools and browser's local storage:

[image]

[image]

Please help me find and fix the issue.

Here is the code of my root component `App.js` which contains my Redux store and local storage funtions:

```
import Servicesdata from "./ServicesData";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducer from "./Reducer";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

// Local Storage Functions:
function saveToLocalStorage(state) {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem("state", serializedState);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}

function loadFromLocalStorage() {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem("state");
    if (serializedState === null) return undefined;
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return undefined;
  }
}

//initial store
const initialStore = {
  services: Servicesdata,
  cart: [],
  bill: 0,
  // quantity: 0,
  total_items: 0, //saves total items in the cart
};

const persistedState = loadFromLocalStorage();

//store
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  persistedState,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

store.subscribe(() => saveToLocalStorage(store.getState));

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
        //more code
    </Provider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

In my `Reducer.js`, I am just dispatching an `INCREASE` action to add a new item to the cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `store.getState` to `store.getState()`.